# Gcc compiler suppress comparison warning

Tags: c++, c

I getting below warning. How to suppress this warning?

Warning:

```
warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: 'DWORD' {aka 'unsigned int'} and 'int' [-Wsign-compare]
```

Code:

```
DWORD exp = GetExp();
int amount = 20;

if (amount < 0 && exp < -amount)
{
...
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to suppress it? You should address it.

Comment: Aside: [tag:C] or [tag:c++] -- you must pick one or the other.

Comment: Please also search for the error message online! As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Change `int amount = 20;` to `DWORD amount = 20;`.  Or change `DWORD exp = GetExp();` to `int exp = static_cast<int>(GetExp());`.

Comment: A good answer requires explaining how to rewrite the code so that the problem the compiler is warning you about does not occur. That is, to rewrite the code so that the comparison operates as intended. However, it seems likely you have omitted some relevant code between the declaration of `amount` and the comparison. As shown, the comparison would only ever be true if `exp` were a very large number. That does not seem like the actual intent. The names suggest some attempt to test whether the positive expense in `exp` is less in magnitude than negative amount in `amount`.

Comment: If that is the case, then, rather than suppress the warning, you should use a cast or other operations to effect the desired comparison. To get a good answer, explain what the purpose of `if (amount < 0 && exp < -amount)` is.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to suppress it (it's not recommended, there is a reason a warning is shown, and you should instead eliminate the reason), you can do it by adding `-Wno-sign-compare` to the `gcc` command line.

Comment: You do not eliminate the reason by disabling the warning! You said it, there is a reason for that warning.

Comment: @ErdalKüçük i know, thats what i stated in my answer !

Comment: I know, i criticized the solution to surpress the warning.